# curl, split string and exit if needed

Tags: bash, split

This is an output when run `curl --silent localhost:9091/health`

```
# HELP metrics_qollector_ttt_health_check The status of ttt.
# TYPE metrics_qollector_ttt_health_check gauge
metrics_qollector_ttt_health_check 1.0
# HELP metrics_qollector_database_health_check The status of the database.
# TYPE metrics_qollector_database_health_check gauge
metrics_qollector_database_health_check 1.0
# HELP metrics_qollector_health_checks_latency_seconds Health check latency in seconds.
# TYPE metrics_qollector_health_checks_latency_seconds summary
metrics_qollector_health_checks_latency_seconds_count{method="runtime",} 1.0
metrics_qollector_health_checks_latency_seconds_sum{method="runtime",} 9.51166E-4
```

I need to boil a bash script that checks if `metrics_qollector_ttt_health_check == "1.0"` or `metrics_qollector_database_health_check == "1.0"` then `exit 0;` else `exit 1;`

What I have been trying to do is the following

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e

HEALTHSTATUS=$(curl --silent localhost:9091/health)

for item in ${HEALTHSTATUS}
    if [[ item[0] = "metrics_qollector_ttt_health_check" && item[1] = "1.0" ]  || [ item[0] = "metrics_qollector_database_health_check" && item[1] "1.0" ]]; then
        exit 0;
    else
        exit 1;
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep -q` exits with status 0 if a match was found and exists with status 1 if no match was found. You can replace your whole script with the following one-liner:

```
curl --silent localhost:9091/health |
grep -Eq '^metrics_qollector_(ttt|database)_health_check 1\.0$'
```

Comment: The only problem with this solution is when the latter string is 0.0, it `exits 0`, but I would like it to `exit 1` if either of the two strings is 1.0, how is that achieved?

Comment: @JonB I'm not sure if I understand correctly. Isn't that exactly the opposite if what you asked in the question? Can you list all cases and the expected output? `ttt 1.0 and dat 1.0 → exit 1`, `ttt 1.0 and dat 0.0 → exit ...`, `ttt missing and ...` and so on.

Comment: `metrics_qollector_ttt_health_check 1.0`
`metrics_qollector_database_health_check 0.0`
If either `ttt` or `database` have values `0.0`I whant to return `exit 1`

Comment: `ttt 1.0 and dat 1.0` = exit = 0
`ttt 1.0 and dat 0.0` = exit = 1
`ttt 0.0 and dat 1.0` = exit = 1
`ttt 0.0 and dat 0.0` = exit = 1

Comment: worth pointing out this works
`if cat health | grep -Eq '^metrics_qollector_(trafero|database)_health_check 0.0$'; then
    echo "exit 1";
else
    echo "exit 0";
fi`
because I kind of reversed the status code from default!

Answer (score 1):

You have so many ways of doing this, but here is one:

```
#!/bin/bash

STATUS=$(curl --silent http://localhost:9091/health | egrep "^metrics_qollector_ttt_health_check |^metrics_qollector_database_health_check ")

EXIT_STATUS=$(echo $STATUS | awk '{if(NF == 4) { if(($2 == 0) || ($4 == 0)) {print "0"} else {print "1"} } else {print "2"}}')

exit $EXIT_STATUS
```

awk should parse your float values (1.0) to numeric values for comparison. It also checks if you have both metrics.

**the script exit codes**:

0 - At least one of the values is 0.0

1 - None of the values is 0.0

2 - If for some reason you don't have one or both metrics in your
    health API